# Can bjam tell you each time it has finished building a target?

Tags: bjam

I am building a script that notifies me of the progress of my builds. At the beginning of the build, `bjam` tells me "updating # targets...".

Does `bjam` have the functionality to notify you every time it finishes building a certain target? Ideally I want to `grep` the output for these and output a percentage to my screen.

Comment: you ought to switch to b2 now.

Comment: What is `b2`, is it similar to `bjam`?

Comment: Yes, it is bjam's replacement.

Answer (score 1):

After using bjam I finally realized that the answer was in front of me the whole time. It turns out that for every target being built it will output the object name to the screen. So in my case I came up with a solution that has a reasonable approximation to the number of targets, by counting the corresponding `*.o` and `*.so` lines at a given time. Hopefully this can help someone else in the future!

I created an alias called `Bjam`:

```
alias Bjam=' reset ; sudo bjam  -j4 release address-model=32 toolset=gcc-arm target-os=linux threading=multi | Bjam2'
```

and a shell script called `Bjam2`:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
while read line; do
if [ $(echo $line | grep -c '^...updating.*targets...$') -eq 1 ] ; then
TOT=$(echo $line|  sed 's|^\.\.\.updating \([0-9]*\) targets\.\.\.$|\1|' )

fi
if [ $(echo $line | grep -c '^gcc\.compile\.c++.*\.o$' ) -eq 1 ] || [ $(echo $line | grep -c '^.*\.so$' ) -eq 1 ]; then
    n=$((n+1))
    echo "$n/$TOT : $line"
else
    echo $line
fi
done
```